# How to change settings in php.ini to include php scripts in html files?

Tags: php, html

I need to include php scripts in my html files.
I contacted my server people and they said I need to change settings in php.ini in my root folder. (godaddy's server)
I need to know the settings that I need to do in php.ini file 
OR
if there is some alternative way to do so then plz tell that.

Comment: Why didn't you ask your server people which settings to change and to what value to change them?

Comment: You rather should change server configuration file(s), eg. .htaccess for Apache.

Answer (score 4):

They lied to you.
No php.ini could help you to control html files. It's web-server's config responsibility.

And, strictly speaking, you shouldn't do it anyway.
PHP is PHP and HTML is HTML.

Rename your html files to php if you want to use PHP in them

Comment: they LIED! the world is full of lies. Even the cake is a lie!

Answer (score 3):

Create an .htaccess (in the root directory) file with the following line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

This let you run all .html files as .php files.

**P.S.**

Most of the Shared Hosting Services that a lot of Hosting Providers use are disabling CGI. When this is your case you should aks your provider to enable it.

Comment: this will let me include php files OR will make php work in html files??

Comment: this wont work as its not letting my html files run as it is.

Comment: Do you run on an Apache environment ?

Comment: yes its php apache environment

Comment: read the postscript @w3developer probably your environment does not support CGI.